# How do I move a usb device to another account in OSX

Tags: macos, usb, user-accounts, iphone

I have a mac mini that my wife and I use to backup our iPhones. Currently we both have user accounts that are both admin accounts. We use our laptops to control the mini from remote. The problem comes in when one of our accounts is logged into the console plugging in the iPhone links that phone to that account. If I unplug the phone and then switch who is logged into the console and plug the phone it is now linked to that account. Is there a way to change which account has control over a given USB port after it's already been connected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to uncheck the "Automatically sync when this iPhone is connected" option from ONE of your iTunes accounts.  This option is shown in the Summary tab of the iPhone section of iTunes.  You can leave the phone plugged in and switch back and forth between accounts, and it will only sync with the one(s) that is/are enabled with this option.  And for best results, each iOS device should be synced with only ONE iTunes library.